# listagg function throwing error ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, listagg

I am using listagg  after cte in stored proc. However, it is returning error ' ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long'. Below is my stored procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_market
IS
    Names VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
    WITH CTE(sqql) As 
    (
      SELECT   field_name sqql FROM   pld_medicare_config  
    )  
    SELECT listagg(sqql, ' UNION ALL ') within GROUP (ORDER BY 1) into Names   from CTE;      
END sp_market;
```

In select query, field_name returns long texts. I believe this is because listagg is not able to handle long characters that is result of select statement. How is work around for this issue?

Comment: What is the expected size of the result ? is it less or greater than 4000 characters? 32767 characters?

Comment: Your CTE doesn't have the `sqql` value you're trying top aggregate. Presumably you've changed things for posting, but it's a bit confusing.

Comment: expected size is way greater that 4000 characters.

Comment: updated my question..

Comment: It does not matter how the plsql variable (name) is declared. The listagg function builds in SQL the complete string. That limit remains 4000. Notice the error is  'ORA-01489: result of string concatenation:   not "ORA-06502: ... string buffer too small". The error occurred before the attempt to put it into the plsql variable. You choice seems to be xml or to build it build it in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

Try `XMLAGG` instead, e.g.

```
with cte as (select id, field_name sqql from pld_medicare_config)
select rtrim (
          xmlagg (xmlelement (e, sqql || ', ') order by null).extract (
             '//text()'),
          ', ')
  into names
  from cte;
```

Comment: I got error  - ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small. Any idea ?

Comment: @CodesDDecodes - your OUT variable `Names` may need to be a CLOB too; either way the variable declaration in whatever calls your procedure has to match the argument type and size (though you don't normally give a size for a varchar2 argument...)

Comment: I did this:                                                                                                               
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_pld_validation_medicare
 IS
    Names CLOB;
BEGIN  .. END  -- But still same erro